# how to show or hide drop down based on text box using javascript

Tags: drop-down-menu, textbox, controls

I want to just expand the drop down list while on focus or on click or on enter text in text box and the focus remains should be in text box, it should just show the drop down list contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $('#textbox').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('.dropdown-menu').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('.dropdown open').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Finally i found solution for this. I found it earlier but post here after long time. Here is the code to do this